# Discord Online Members Counter

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've started messing with discord.js and am now trying to make a bot. I made a simple member counter:

```js
module.exports = async (client) => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('$$$$$');
    setInterval(() => {
        const memberCount = guild.memberCount;
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('$$$$$');
        channel.setName(`Aventureiros: ${memberCount.toLocaleString()}`);
        console.log('Updating Member Count');
    }, 900000);
}
```

How can I make an ONLINE member counter? I'm looking for something online and there seems to be no tutorials on this.

Comment: As in the number of members who are online?

Comment: Yes, i found things like filter, but im new to discord.js, so ive no idea how to use it

Answer (score 2):

You will need to access the entire collection of members, then filter the ones who are online

```
const memberCollection = guild.members.cache;
const onlineCount = memberCollection.filter(member => {
   member.presence.status === 'online'
}).size;
```

In some situations, you might have to fetch the guild first.